# Java - totalling value of cards. Comparing values of array with positions in another array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am making a method to return an array of integers of the total of all the cards and the total number of jokers and aces in the users 'cards' array.  It uses a for loop and finds the value of the card in an array containing the cards in their order.  If the card's value is greater than 10, the value 10 should be added to the total.

Here is the index array:

```
 static String[] cardOrder = {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};
```

And here is the method:

```
public static int[] total(ArrayList<String> cards){
        int total = 0;
        int aces = 0;
        int jokers = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(cards.size());
            System.out.println("One of your cards is " + cards.get(i));
            if(cards.get(i).equals("A")){
                aces = aces + 1;
            }else if(cards.get(i).equals("Joker")){
                jokers = jokers + 1;
            }else{
                if(Arrays.asList(cardOrder).indexOf(cards.get(i)) <= 10){
                    total = total + Arrays.asList(cardOrder).indexOf(cards.get(i)) + 1;
                }else{
                    total = total + 10;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(total);
            i++;
        }
        int[] intArray = {total, aces, jokers};
        return intArray;
    }
```

However, strange things appear to be happening.  I get out of bounds exceptions when I change the greater than sign in the for loop to greater than or equal to, but when I do not do this, only the first value of the cards array is counted.

Sorry that this looks like a 'fix my code' type of thread.  I think it will be useful to the Java beginner community in terms of enhancing their understanding of the use of arrays and arraylists within Java methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have i++ in your for loop AND at the end of your for loop. Remove the bottom one

Comment: But does that explain the out of bounds exceptions ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat The out of bounds exception happens when he uses `i <= cards.size()` clearly because at the last iteration, `i = card.size()` and `cards.get(cards.size())` is out of bounds.

Comment: @Smutje I agree that the problem is because of `<=`.  Whereas the above answer addresses another problem it does not address the question that the OP posted.

Comment: The problem he had when he WASNT using <= is that only the first card was counted. My guess is there were 2 cards in the array and because i was incremented twice, the second card is ignored. My answer addresses that problem

Answer (score 1):

The important thing that you need to remember about java Arrays is that, their indexing starts from '0' but not from '1'. When you create an array of size '2', to access the first array element you need to use index '0' (something like arr[0]) and to access the second array element you need to use the index '1'.

This understanding would be good enough to overcome the out of bounds exceptions. Just go through the code carefully and see when ever you are accessing the array element, you are not using the index which is less than '0' (or) greater than 'size-1' (i.e if you create an array of size 'N', the index can not be less than '0' and can not be greater than N-1).